# node packages are loaded from wrong path

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have this issue on global packages, that if I run `npm install -g <package>` that packages are installed into `/Users/myUsername/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/node_modules` which seems correct to me.

But it runs packages from:
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Thus these packages never get updated/ if I delete a package from there and install it globally it is not available afterwards. If I copy the package after installing from the nvm to the local folder it works.

1) Are the packages supposed to be in the nvm path or in the local one?

2) How to use the correct path?

Comment: Whom do you refer in this statement "he runs packages from" ?

Comment: What does your `$PATH` look like? It sounds something there is not set up properly

Comment: `-bash: /Users/MasterG/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql:/usr/local/php5-5.6.5-20150201-150908/bin/:/Users/MasterG/.composer/vendor/bin:/Applications/mongodb/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You should install all dependencies locally if you plan to use them in your node application and make sure it is listed under `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file.
If you intend to use them only from cmd line then you can install globally so that it'll be available from any path in your terminal.

You don't need to mention from where node_modules will be loaded in your node application.

Comment: Hi, I know but I have packages like nodemon, yeoman etc. which I want to use globally but as mentioned the installation path and the path where node is requiring the global packages are different.

Comment: With `local one` I mean `/usr/local/...` not local in a sense of a local installation.